# Transfer data from one page to another

Tags: javascript, next.js

I created a site in NextJs, on which you can connect with your Discord account and I was then able (in the oauth file) to retrieve the user's guilds.

And I would like to send these guilds (json file) to my dashboard page.

oauth.tsx :

```
export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
...
  const guildsuser = await fetch("http://discord.com/api/users/@me/guilds", {
    headers: { Authorization: `${token_type} ${access_token}` },
  });
  const guilds = guildsuser.json();
}
```

here is the `guilds` constant that I would like to send to the dashboard page to display it

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use an API route? I'd recommend having a read through [Next.js API Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction).

Comment: I looked at it several times but I don't see how to send data from one page to another, especially since my data is in a default export. And I cannot precisely target this given in the 2nd page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I think I'll pass the data through cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, you're just missing one line of code to send the `guilds` back to the front-end dashboard.

```
export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
...
  const guildsuser = await fetch("http://discord.com/api/users/@me/guilds", {
    headers: { Authorization: `${token_type} ${access_token}` },
  });
  const guilds = await guildsuser.json();
  res.status(200).json({ guilds })
}
```

*Note: there should also be `await` before `guilduser.json()` as shown here*

You can find many more options about how to send the response in the docs:

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/response-helpers

Comment: okay and then in my dashboard.tsx file I just have to : 
`import guilds from "oauth";`
?

Comment: because my real problem and I don't know how to import the guilds element on the dashboard page to serve me